# Character Theory for quaternionic representations of finite groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Is  there  a nice  character  Theory  for quaternionic representations  of  finite  groups?

By  this  I  mean  a  description  of   the  number  of  Quaternionic  representations  of a  finite  group in  terms  of  Conjugacy  classes/ equivalence  classes   of  elements in G  of  some  sort, in analogy  with  the  real  character  theory  in terms  of  conjugacy  classes  of  real  elements?

Comment: One thought is that it might be possible to do something along these lines if you knew how many square roots (in $G$) each element of $G$ has. But in practice, this seems an unrealistic requirement. But, for the record, an irreducible character $\chi$ of $G$ has F-S indicator $-1$ if and only if $\sum_{g \in G}(\#$ square roots of $g$ )$\chi(g^{-1}) = -|G|$).